# Socomec UPS no longer powers on after power failure

Tags: ups

Some time ago I was bought a Socomec NETYS PR RT 1700 and a B2200 extender as payment for a job, intending to use it for a project that fell through sometime later.  I started at a new job as IT Manager and, as cash for IT was scarce at the time, loaned my UPS to them for the purpose of keeping their kit running during outages.

One day someone cut off the power to move a power point as part of an office reconfiguration (nobody was informed of this until some minutes after it happened) and when they did that, the UPS (which was overloaded due to a consultant who didn't brain when they installed their equipment, long story) shut off, at which point someone went into the server room to try to power it back on again, at which point the UPS shut off again.  However, even when the power was switched back on, the UPS didn't turn back on and was not passing power through to the servers and switches.

I've popped the cover on this one (it's way out of warranty so I figured it couldn't hurt to have a look) hoping to find a fuse that might have popped, but I can't see anything of the sort.  Plugging in the UPS with a Kill-A-Watt shows some power use, but nothing appears on the front LCD screen and none of the buttons seem to do anything.  None of the capacitors seem to be blown or missing.

Is this UPS dead, or is there some hope to revive it?

Comment: I think, UPS now has very lower batteries. It must charge batteries up to about 20℅ before starting. UPS can  charge batteries in off regime. Plug in and try power on UPS after an hour.

Comment: I left it plugged in for a few days, no change.

Comment: If input fuse is good you need to buy new UPS.